# Android Camera flash not turning on after turned off

Tags: android, camera

I have a button on my camera preview screen to toggle the camera's flash. The camera starts on auto-flash which works then when the button is pressed the flash turns off but when i try to turn the flash back on it doesn't turn on and i don't know why?

```
Log.d("flash",mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode());
```

Displays on off and auto as i press it. But it doesn't turn back on. Here is my full code

```
public void flashPressed(View v)
{
    ImageButton flashButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.flash);
    Camera.Parameters myP = mCamera.getParameters();
    if(flashOn == 0)
    {
        flashButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.device_access_flash_off);

        myP.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        flashOn = 1;

    }
    else if(flashOn == 1)
    {
        myP.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        flashButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.device_access_flash_on);
        flashOn=2;
    }else{
        myP.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_AUTO);
        flashButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.device_access_flash_automatic);
        flashOn =0;
    }

    mCamera.setParameters(myP);
    Log.d("flash",mCamera.getParameters().getFlashMode());
}
```

Comment: I am testing this on two different phones for one phone it works as expected the other it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this problem I just created a new camera each time the flash option changes

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used to create a Flash app.

```
public class Flash extends Activity {
    boolean cameraOpened;
    static Camera camFlash = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (camFlash != null) {
            camFlash.stopPreview();
            camFlash.release();
            camFlash = null;

        }

    }

    public void turnOnFlash(View view) {
        if (camFlash == null) {
            camFlash = Camera.open();
        }
        if (camFlash != null) {
            Parameters params = camFlash.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camFlash.setParameters(params);
            camFlash.startPreview();
            camFlash.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public void turnOffFlash(View view) {
        if (camFlash != null) {
            camFlash.stopPreview();
            camFlash.release();
            camFlash = null;
        }
    }
}
```

the methods turnOnFlash() and turnOffFlash are called from xml android:onClick.